# Using Linear Layout with TextInputLayout but facing a problem

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

[The image is a screenshot of the fragment in which I have applied the Linear Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BQVs.jpg)

The XML file of the layout is below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/select_product_image"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/category_spinner"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/input_design"
        />
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

        app:shapeAppearance="@style/Rounded"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/product_name"
            android:inputType="text"

            />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

        app:shapeAppearance="@style/Rounded"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/product_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/product_description"
            android:maxLength="100"
            android:inputType="text"

            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

        app:shapeAppearance="@style/Rounded"
        app:endIconMode="clear_text"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/product_price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/product_price"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"

            />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_new_product"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="@string/add_product"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        />



    </LinearLayout>
```

The layout file in which I am using this is given below

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NavigActivity">


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
            app:menu="@menu/menu"
            app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
            />
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"

            app:maxImageSize="35dp"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have set the orientation of the LinearLayout vertical but it is working not properly..I wanted each of the attributes one below the other and in the center (Horizontally). Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: Post the other layout XML also in which you are using this layout ...

Comment: @PraveenSP I have posted that layout also

Comment: Set layout width for each component to match_parent

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin thnx sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the frame layout width from **wrap_content** to **match_parent**

Use this layout :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".NavigActivity">


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
            app:menu="@menu/menu"
            app:buttonGravity="center_vertical"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
            />
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"

            app:maxImageSize="35dp"/>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
 />

</RelativeLayout>
```